# How do you raise a .Net event from an IronRuby class?

Tags: ironruby

I'm trying to figure out how to implement an event in a ruby class.  Specifically, I am trying to make my class implement an interface (INotifyPropertyChanged) that includes an event (PropertyChanged).  I can create my add_PropertyChanged and remove_PropertyChanged methods... but then what?

This is what my class looks like so far:

```
class TestClass
    include System::ComponentModel::INotifyPropertyChanged

    def add_PropertyChanged(handler)
    end

    def remove_PropertyChanged(handler)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Here is how you do it:

```
class TestClass
    include System::ComponentModel::INotifyPropertyChanged

    def initialize
        @change_handlers = []
    end

    def add_PropertyChanged(handler)
        @change_handlers << handler
    end

    def remove_PropertyChanged(handler)
        @change_handlers.delete(handler)
    end

    def NotifyPropertyChanged(name)
        @change_handlers.each { |h| h.invoke(self, System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventArgs.new(name)) }
    end
end
```